# Отключить автоматический запуск скрипта на вход в oauth google

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Данный скрипт

```
(function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = false;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
```

автоматически запускает функцию которая совершает авторизацию при посещении сайта (я даже не успеваю нажать на кнопку Войти). Как остановить автоматическое вызывание данного скрипта при запуске?

Comment: Удалите его, тогда и вызываться он не будет автоматически.

Comment: @Visman, а как тогда кнопку подгружать?

Comment: Вставка различных виджетов, лайковых и +1 кнопок со сторонних сайтов позволяет владельцам этих сайтов делать на вашей странице у пользователя в браузере все что угодно. Нужен вам +1 на странице, миритесь с этим.

Comment: Но у фб есть опция как не запускать это автоматом, а здесь?

Comment: Посмотрите документацию https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

Comment: в ней то то и дело написано, что после подтверждения условий на вход каждый раз он будет автоматическим.